# Correct parsing of JavaScript octal escape sequence

Tags: javascript

According to the ECMA spec an octal escape sequence is defined as

```
OctalEscapeSequence ::  
    OctalDigit [lookahead ∉ DecimalDigit]  
    ZeroToThree OctalDigit [lookahead ∉ DecimalDigit]  
    FourToSeven OctalDigit  
    ZeroToThree OctalDigit OctalDigit  

ZeroToThree :: one of
    0 1 2 3

FourToSeven :: one of
    4 5 6 7
```

According to this spec a string `"\379"` is not an octal escape `\37` followed by `9`. Am I reading this right? It doesn't satisfy the first rule, since 7 is a decimal digit. It doesn't satisfy the second, since 9 is a decimal digit. It doesn't satisfy the third, since three is not one of `4 5 6 7`. Finally, it doesn't satisfy the fourth, since 9 is not an octal digit.

So what is the value of `"\379"` then? I tried a couple of JavaScript translators, they interpret it as an octal escape `\37` followed by `9`. Is it a bug in the interpreters?

#### UPDATE

I know that octal escape sequences are optional in the latest ECMA spec.

Comment: I'd say it's a bug in the spec.  They really should `s/DecimalDigit/OctalDigit/g`.  :P

Comment: I tend to agree this is probably a bug in the spec :). Ok, I was thinking maybe I just don't understand something, now I know I'm ok.

Answer (score 2):

The octal escape sequence is not part of the official spec implemented by modern browsers.

> ## [B.1 Additional Syntax](http://es5.github.io/#B.1)
>
> Past editions of ECMAScript have included additional syntax and semantics for specifying octal literals and octal escape sequences. **These have been removed from this edition of ECMAScript**. This non-normative annex presents uniform syntax and semantics for octal literals and octal escape sequences for compatibility with some older ECMAScript programs.

and it's explicitly disallowed in strict mode:

> ## B.1.1 Numeric Literals
>
> The syntax and semantics of 7.8.3 can be extended as follows **except that this extension is not allowed for strict mode code**

---

Given that, `\379` is not an octal escape sequence since the negative lookahead of decimal digit bars both `\3` and `\37` from being treated as octal escape sequences.

This is then a syntax error since no other production matches it.  Specifically,

```
CharacterEscapeSequence ::
  SingleEscapeCharacter
  NonEscapeCharacter
```

(which is what causes `"\-"` to be equal to `"-"`) does not apply because digits are not in `SingleEscapeCharacter` nor in `NonEscapeCharacter`.

---

> Is it a bug in the interpreters?

Maybe not if it only happens in unstrict mode.  Interpreters are allowed to define additional syntax per chapter 16:

> An implementation may extend program syntax and regular expression pattern or flag syntax.

An interpreter author could probably make a case that they're a conforming implementation with this behavior, they just extend syntax to support octal in a different way than that *suggested* by section B.1.